# ContactsService gdata java client setUserCredentials throws exception

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

In my java app engine application I am using Google Contacts Api v3.0. I am using serUserCredentials method and passing useremail and password. This was working fine. But now Even after correct user email and password it throws "Invalid Credentials" exception.

com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:586)
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:490)
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:336)
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:362)
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:337)

It is not happening for all the users. Could you please suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm getting this too.  If you log in as your user and visit https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity does it warn you of unusual activity?